# Azure Bitnami WordPress: Cannot get third-party SSL cert to be picked up by server

Tags: wordpress, azure, bitnami

I'm following this documentation to finalize SSL configuration, using a third-party-provided certificate, but having issues: https://docs.bitnami.com/azure/apps/wordpress/administration/enable-https-ssl-apache/

I've added the following entries to /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/bitnami-ssl.conf, in order to replace the working LetsEncrypt certificates with my new ones. (domain names are obviously obfuscated in the file screenshot, but it does match filenames in the directory)
[image: Screenshot of bitnami-ssl.conf]

Here is a screenshot showing the directory where the certificates are held. Permissions look correct, I believe.
[image]

After getting the configuration in place, I restarted all Bitnami services, and even Apache explicitly, but this new cert doesn't seem to get picked up by the server/browser.

Did I miss something? Perplexed here....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here,

You are editing the SSL certificates to use for the default VirtualHost of Apache. However, the WordPress app also has another VirtualHost for it. In order to use the new SSL certificates when accessing WordPress, you will need to edit the `/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/wordpress-https-vhost.conf` file.

> Note: I'll notify the Bitnami documentation team to update the documentation accordingly.

Comment: That's it, thanks so much! And, thanks for having the team add it to the documentation, I'm sure that will help others in my situation.